# C++, почему std::async() требует наличия конструктора по умолчанию у возвращаемого объекта?

Tags: c++, конструктор, future, default

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace std;    

class Object
{
public:

  Object(bool b)
  {

  }
};

Object func()
{
  Object object(true);
  return object;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  future<Object> future_object;// 1, тут все ок.

  future_object = async(func);// 2, тут нет конструктора по умолчанию.

  return 0;
}
```

Я совершенно не понимаю, зачем во втором случае требуется конструктор по умолчанию. В книгах этой информации не нашел. Буду благодарен за любую помощь или ссылку.

Comment: Похоже, что вам нужно кидать код целиком. [Все собирается](https://ideone.com/CcF45V).

Comment: @MrBin, при компиляции в `VS 2019` я получаю ошибку `C2512`. Это исчерпывающий код.

Comment: Кидайте в вопрос ошибку.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно обновить компилятор от майков. [Вот](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60897/c-shared-state-futuresstate-default-constructs-the.html) это проблема.

Comment: @MrBin, большое спасибо вам за помощь. Не могли бы вы оформить ответ? Я уверен, он окажется полезным и поможет другим людям сэкономить нервы и время.

Comment: Комментария достаточно.

Comment: @MrBin, в какой версии компилятора данная проблема гарантированно исправлена? Я использую `v142 (14.24)`,  проблема присутствует.

Comment: Надо проверять.